# Terraform state environments/workspaces not listed when created on another machine

Tags: terraform

I've been using Terraform's [state environments](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) ([soon to be renamed as workspaces](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0100-beta1-june-22-2017)) as part of a CI system (Gitlab CI) to spin up dynamic environments for each branch for tests to run against.

This seems to be working fine but as part of the tear down of the `environment` after the branch is deleted I am also trying to use `terraform env delete [ENVIRONMENT NAME]`. When ran locally this is fine but my CI system is running in Docker and so has a clean workspace between creating the environment and then later on a build stage destroying it. In this case it can't seem to see the `environment`.

If I try to delete it I see this error:

```
Environment "restrict-dev-websites-internally" doesn't exist!

You can create this environment with the "new" option.
```

`terraform env list` also doesn't show the environment.

I've also noticed that I'm unable to select it despite seeing it in S3 (where my remote state is stored). If I create a new environment called the same thing then the environment from my remote state is used (it doesn't try to create another set of resources).

On top of this, when I'm using an environment created by the CI system I notice that sometimes I have an environment selected that `terraform env list` doesn't show:

```
$ terraform env list
  default
$ cat .terraform/environment 
[ENVIRONMENT NAME]
$ terraform env list
  default
```

Note the missing `*` against the selected environment and that my environment isn't listed as would be expected by the example in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/workspace/list.html):

```
$ terraform env list
  default
* development
  mitchellh-test
```

I'm unsure as to how the state environments are meant to be working so I may have missed a trick here which is causing this odd corruption when working in Docker.

For completeness I'm managing the environments using some wrapper scripts:

#### env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./env.sh terraform_target env_name"
  echo ""
  echo "Example: ./env.sh test test-branch"
fi

TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION=${1}
TERRAFORM_ENV=${2}

REPO_BASE=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
TERRAFORM_BASE="${REPO_BASE}"/terraform

. "${TERRAFORM_BASE}"/remote.sh "${TERRAFORM_BASE}"/"${TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION}"

if ! terraform env select ${TERRAFORM_ENV} 2> /dev/null; then
  terraform env new ${TERRAFORM_ENV}
fi
```

#### env-delete.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./env.sh terraform_target env_name"
  echo ""
  echo "Example: ./env.sh test test-branch"
fi

TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION=${1}
TERRAFORM_ENV=${2}

REPO_BASE=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
TERRAFORM_BASE="${REPO_BASE}"/terraform

. "${TERRAFORM_BASE}"/remote.sh "${TERRAFORM_BASE}"/"${TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION}"

if terraform env select ${TERRAFORM_ENV} 2> /dev/null; then
  terraform env select default
  terraform env delete ${TERRAFORM_ENV}
fi
```

The remote.sh script runs a `terraform init` with dynamic state file locations depending on the project and path in the project using S3 as a backend.

#### remote.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

terraform --version

TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION="${1}"

cd "${TERRAFORM_TARGET_LOCATION}"

REPO_NAME="$(basename "`git config --get remote.origin.url`" .git)"
STATE_BUCKET="<BUCKET_NAME>"
STATE_KEY="$(git rev-parse --show-prefix | cut -d"/" -f2-)"
STATE_FILE="terraform.tfstate"

terraform init -backend-config="bucket=${STATE_BUCKET}" \
               -backend-config="key=${STATE_KEY}/${STATE_FILE}"

terraform get -update=true
```

When running things locally I have very wide permissions which include full access to all of S3. My Gitlab CI instances use the following IAM privileges attached to an instance profile:

```
{
  "Version"  : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid"     :   "1",
      "Effect"  :   "Allow",
      "Action"  : [ "s3:List*",
                    "s3:Get*",
                    "s3:PutObject*" ],
      "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*" ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:DeleteObject*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/env:*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For clarity, my builds can see and use the remote state for the environment fine but are forced to created the environment over and over and are then unable to delete the environment after destroying everything in the state file because it can't select the environment.

I *could* always create the environment before deleting it so that I have it available in `terraform env list` but the point is that I'm not sure why the environment is not in the list when the environment was created on another machine or in another container.

Comment: Would you mind adding the `remote.sh` source code (redacted or simplified if necessary) to the question here? I'd help to be able to see how you have the backend configured since some details of how environments work vary depending on the backend settings.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I've added the remote.sh script if that helps. All of my helper scripts source the remote.sh script (as you can see with the env scripts above) before executing the command they are focused on.

Comment: Do you have any unusual/granular IAM policies applied to this S3 bucket? I'm wondering if there are any constraints on `s3:ListBucket` that would cause Terraform to get an incomplete list of the objects in the bucket. Terraform looks for objects matching a certain prefix in order to recognize an object as a workspace state.

Comment: @MartinAtkins When running locally I have full access to everything in S3 in this account. My Gitlab CI runners have a more restrictive IAM policy that I've included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need the state to destroy the environment.
From the documentation as to why they need the state:

> Terraform typically uses the configuration to determine dependency
>   order. However, when you delete a resource from a Terraform
>   configuration, Terraform must know how to delete that resource.
>   Terraform can see that a mapping exists for a resource not in your
>   configuration and plan to destroy. However, since the configuration no
>   longer exists, it no longer knows the proper destruction order.

You might also try [to first import it](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) which might be doable if there are not many instances involved.
I'd suggest considering [running a consul container](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) (or 3 to make it stable, they are really small) to store the state in another remote store than your default s3 store. This will make sure your CI environments will not show up in the remote store used by others. Consul has a web gui that will allow you to clean up the K/V stored there if it is ever needed. You can also interact with it through their api using curl or Ansible.
Alternatively, you can make the consul server part of the dev environment you set up, store the state there and read from it when destroying. In that case you would still keep everything else clean. I'd personally do it like this.

If a dev starts an environment on his local machine and you want to keep your remote state clean he should be using the local state. You can also use the solution above for the dev's local machine and have a consul server inside his local setup. Good for him to create/destroy and you will keep you remote state clean as you say.

As a disclaimer, I only started recently with Terraform but I don't quite see the advantage of the environments. I'm using a git repo with subdirs for each environment. That way they are truly independent from each other and I can set a dev locally and our staging/prod on our consul cluster protected with ACL.

Comment: You misunderstand. I have access to the state it's just that the environment doesn't appear in `terraform env list` and trying to select it fails. If I create the environment with the same name then the remote state is valid (as expected because it's there in S3). And I'm only using the envs for this because it _has_ to be dynamic as the environment is different for every branch pushed to the repo. For everything else I'm using different folders and state files which is simpler but less flexible.

Comment: In that case it sounds more like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try the Volumes option in runner configuration?
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runners-docker-section
To save the terraform state between builds?

Comment: I'd rather not share state between builds (I'm building in Docker precisely to keep builds clean) but it also doesn't save me from my issue that environments created on another machine (say another dev's workstation) isn't obviously available for other people.